# 72 Names of God pendants

Tags: halacha, shemos-sacred-names, jewelry

Is there a problem wearing [72 Names of God pendants](http://www.yourholylandstore.com/72-names-of-god-jewelry/)? Or unlike the sacred Name of God from the Torah it is allowed? The sacred name in the Torah is YHVH (in Hebrew letters Yud Hey Vav Hey) and as far as I know it is not only forbidden to pronounce it but also to wear it as a jewelry of any kind.

Comment: Thanks for your edit; that's much clearer. I hope you get the answers you seek! But don't forget that this site makes no guarantee of validity, and does not offer professional (particularly rabbinic) advice. Treat information from this site like it came from a crowd of your friends and bring it to [your rabbi when you ask him for an halachic ruling](/q/9146).

Comment: Moshe, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for the interesting question! I hope you find more Q&A of interest and stay learning with us!

Comment: @mbloch , Michael, thank you! I am learning a lot from this resource.

Comment: Which of those pendants actually contains the 72 Names?