# Are these Sheimos Hashem?

Tags: shemos-sacred-names, ayin-hara-evil-eye

Someone just showed me an "ayin hara necklace" that has the words "אלד" and "סאל" on the charm and asked me to explain what it means. What are those words?

(Some websites suggest these may be Sheimos Hashem: אלד referring to protection from ayin hara and סאל referring to financial success. If that is true, are these true Sheimos that one cannot enter a bathroom with such a necklace?)

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/70822/72-names-of-god-pendants

Answer (score 0):

They're from the 72 letter name those are two of the 72 they are big money makers for what is called a cult, the Kabbalah Center.

So yes they're Shemoth and but if the name is encased in leather then it's permitted but if in cloth or other material then maybe not (see Shulkhan Arukh 292:4).

[This is one reason Na Nach kameas (necklaces) are usually encased in leather, however this is very different because this is a name that can be pronounced and also [Saba Y. Odesser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yisroel_Ber_Odesser) said it can go everywhere any time; I think that's why you have NN kipas and frash threads, but I may be wrong and that might not be the reason.]

It's best to just get a Na Nach Nachma Nachman meUman kamea for those purposes anyway because it covers everything so says Saba Y. Odesser.

Comment: Interesting - it looks like common words are part of the 72 Letter Name (e.g., מום, אני, כלי) as well. Is each three letter combination considered a Sheim Hashem or only when all 72 letters are together?

Comment: @NJM it does look, I'm inclined for your latter but I don't know, and you know they're just from those three verses laid Forward Backward Forward right.. so.. "It's all Names?"

Comment: ננח והו הוש יענ. ז transliteration Nanach-Wahu Hushia Na